I need assistance on how to get my coin back
Please, I need you assistance.
I sent 88 USDC fanthom from my true wallet to USDC wallet on bybit through BEP20 NETWORK but till now, I have not received it.
Please, kindly assist me on how to recover it.
Thank you all.

Can you post more info like the transaction on the block explorer?

Fanthom is a different network than BSC. With a simple transfer USDC won't change networks. You have to use a bridge to make tokens switch between networks. If you have the transaction hash you could ask bybit if the can recover it.
